# Identify a movie where a person can travel back to recent past by getting inside a box

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel

This request comes from a friend of mine. She heard about a movie where a person could flip a switch on a box, wait a few hours, then get inside the box to travel back to the moment when they switched the box on. This means that when a man turns the box on, he would immediately see a slightly older version of himself leave the box.

A time traveler could turn the box on, check the stock market and lottery numbers, and then go back in time a few hours to buy stocks or buy a lottery ticket.

She believes this movie was made within the last few years. She has not seen the movie, but only heard somebody describe it to her.

Can anybody help my friend by identifying the story?

Comment: Could it be [Primer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primer_(film))

Comment: please note: identifying the movie may lead to your friend _watching_ the movie, which may lead to your friend _trying to figure out_ the movie, which is the opposite of helping.

Comment: @KutuluMike Haha, how true.

Comment: Was the box bigger on the inside by any chance?

Comment: @Machavity - lol. Yes, every single part of this question fits season 1 of Doctor Who.

Comment: The title made me think of calvin and hobbes, and his cardboard box.

Comment: Sounds like TimeCrimes

Comment: Sounds exactly like Primer as answered by Valorum.

Comment: +1 Just because more people should watch this movie.

Comment: @KutuluMike: You may be amused to find [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/130152/626)

Comment: @Valorum Not quite every single part of the question describes the TARDIS in Doctor Who. To my best knowledge, the TARDIS didn't have a timed delay switch on the **outside** for when the box started.

Comment: @RichS - It had an autostart disk thingy

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This sounds an awful lot like [Primer](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0390384/). The protagonists of the film invent a box-like time machine. When turned on, it allows the user to return to the moment that the box was activated.

On several occasions a user sees themselves leaving the facility where the box is stored.

You may find this simple chart helpful when trying to work out what's going on.

[image]

Comment: You could also include the handy graphic from Wikipedia.

Comment: I just showed the Wikipedia entry to my friend. She believes this is the movie that somebody described to her. Thanks.

Comment: [this xkcd comic](https://xkcd.com/657/) (the lowest row in particular) may also come in handy.

Comment: Ah, Primer: Sorta like a cross twixt Dr.Who and Pi.

Comment: This movie breaks my brain.

Comment: Wow, music's _way_ too loud in that trailer.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition - I don't think it was ever intended to be subjected to the kind of intense scrutiny that it has been.

Comment: Re: OP's statement "This means that when a man turns the box on, he would immediately see a slightly older version of himself leave the box", might want to add that the box was equipped with a timer which turned on the box; the user would start the timer and leave the immediate area in order to avoid the self-encounter situation which could cause a paradox.

Comment: @AnthonyX My friend's description didn't mention a delayed timer switch, but I can see why that would be helpful.

Comment: Can you link to the home of that chart(when clicking on it, that is), rather than the low-res imger copy used as the img?  That would also serve to give credit.

Answer (score -10):

The movie is [*Source Code*, the 2011 movie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_Code_(film)).

[image]

Comment: Source Code was nothing like what the OP described.

Comment: Can you please fill in a reason for why this matches the movie that the OP is looking for?

Comment: Don't bother; it doesn't.